# Rasters, ArcMap to Autocad (vanilla)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, geotiff-tiff, export, autocad

If i clip a raster in Arcmap (10.5) and the export it so as to import it into autocad 2018(vanilla using georefimg - not map3d or civil).  it gives me a error message and will not attach the image.   it also will not open in adobe lightroom or infraview.  If I open it in QGIS and save it from there it works... Any thoughts on why?  would love to skip this step and keep all of my processing in arcmap.

Comment: What format are you exporting out as?

Comment: tif with world file

Answer (score 2):

I determined that to export a tiff that will be compatible  with Autocad you must check "Use renderer" and "Force RGB" to produce an 8bit pixel depth raster. Otherwise the the raster will be promoted to a 16bit pixel depth which autocad will not recognize.   Compression, at least LZW compression cannot used either.

Comment: unfortunately this produces a tiff with a white background rather than one capable of being transparent in autocad which would be nice.  Any thoughts on how to get a transparent background without promoting pixel depth?